# Using the Domino Web Login and secondary NAB for non-notes web applications

Tags: web, authentication, lotus-domino, lotus-notes

I tried to do some research on this matter but couldn't really find anything. So, I was just wondering if anyone ever did something like this or if it would even make sense to do it that way:

Lets say, you have a secondary NAB for users who don't have a notes ID but need access to your web-enabled Notes / XPages applications.

Now, a non-notes web application wants to allow the same set of users access to their application.

Could this application use the Domino Web Login, so, user can log in into the non-notes web application?

How would a redirect work after a successful / failed log in attempt?

Would you use JSON / WebServices for that, or how would you implement it?

I know it is a rather general question, but I was just wondering.

Any response would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Daniel

Comment: Are you looking for single sign-on, where logging into Domino automatically logs you into some other web server, and vice versa? Or are you just looking for a common user directory, with separate logins required for each server?

Comment: Hello Richard, thank you very much for your response. The idea is to use the secondary NAB as a common user directory for Notes and Non-Notes Web apps, if that makes sense.

Comment: In that case you should find out if the other server can use LDAP for authentication. If it can, then just configure it to access Domino LDAP.

Comment: Hello Richard, so, if the other application supports LDAP, I can just use the Domino Server as an LDAP provider? Could you please post your comment as an answer (may be with some more details / links if you have them), so I can mark it as the answer to my question?

Comment: I hesitated to make it an answer because now that I understand your requirement it is really more of a ServerFault issue than a StackOverflow issue. But I just did it anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other server can use LDAP for authentication, then you can configure Domino's LDAP task and set up Domino's Directory Assistance to expose your secondary address book to LDAP, and configure the other server to use the Domino LDAP as it's authentication source.

Note that this is not a single sign-on solution, so separate login will still be required for the non-Domino application. It does get you a single authentication source, though.

Comment: Hello Richard, just another question regarding LDAP. Please correct me if I am wrong but, when you use LDAP you get a return of values (i.e. user name, mail address etc.). How does Domino gather these information? Does it use the fields that are on the form or can you set it up somewhere. I would like to provide a functionality that, when the user logs in for the first time, they are forced to change their passwords, so, I'd have to return a flag for that. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Domino uses Domino Directory databases to store the information. I believe that recent versions of Domino have builitin password management features like forced password change - though I could be wrong about that. Building your own, though, is way beyond the scope of what I can advise you on here on StackOverflow. You can build a password change app, and Domino used to even ship with a sample of one, but even though I wrote some of the code in it, I have to say it was pretty limited. It would be hard to force users into it.

Comment: Doing password management the right way on Domino involves using low-level hooks into the Domino HTTP server using the Notes C API Toolkit's DSAPI interface.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard, you've been a great help, I appreciate it

Comment: BTW, I am building a password management app with XPages. I was just wondering if there is a possibility to use LDAP to send back a flag that says, this is the first time log in and the other side could then check for that flag and reroute the user to the password management app to change the password.

Comment: An LDAP query can pass back anything that you store in the Domino Directory. So if you can set up the system to record the number of logins in the Domino Directory, then the other side could check it. You could record that info with a DSAPI plugin. However, if you're going to start playing with DSAPI, then there's no reason to rely on the other side to do the redirection. You would do it directly with your hooks into the HTTP stack.